# Bootstrap datepicker how to allow past 6 months dates

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I enable past 6 months dates from today including today in Bootstrap datepicke.

For example if today is 4th October 2015 then calendar will only allow to pick any date between 4th April 2015 to 4th October 2015.

```
    var date = new Date();
    // initialize daterange
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yy",
        orientation: "top left",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: false,
        toggleActive: false,
        startDate: date
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`startDate` should do it ([doc](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id6))

Answer (score 1):

I'm asuming you are using [this](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id5), so you can make use of `endDate` and `startDate`.

You need to set the `startDate` to the `Date.now - 6 months` and the `endDate` to today.

```
var now = new Date();
var sixmonthsago = new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 6));


$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yy",
    orientation: "top left",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: false,
    toggleActive: false,
    endDate: now,
    startDate: sixmonthsago
});
```

I didint test the code.

Comment: Its not working as per the question asked.Your code only shown Feb 2016 :(